# Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Low Disk Space

Tags: 11.10, filesystem, gparted

I started to receive "Low Disk Space" message on my Ubuntu Oneiric 11.04 few days ago.
With GParted I see that my /dev/sda1 where is system is only 1,17 Gb! and this is obviously not enough. I have 3 more (needed) partitions with enough space and about 28 Gb of unalocated disk space on this phisical disk.
Now I can't turn on terminal with root privileges "Failed to run /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator as user root." anymore because linux is "Unable to copy the user's Xauthorization file".

Question is: Can I increase my /dev/sda1 by adding this unallocated space and how to do this?
Preffered with GParted if possible.
I try to do this by myself but unsuccessfuly. This partition is of ntfs type and here is also system files for windows booting what I choose with grub at startup.

I am not linux guru so please explanation on "simple way".

**Edit**
The output of `df -T` is:

```
Filesystem    Type   1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7     ext4   113036984 107296076         0 100% /
udev      devtmpfs     1987968         4   1987964   1% /dev
tmpfs        tmpfs      798356      1184    797172   1% /run
none         tmpfs        5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none         tmpfs     1995888      3736   1992152   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda3  fuseblk    16383996   9103384   7280612  56% /media/sda3
/dev/sdc1     vfat   312492320  49250336 263241984  16% /media/usb0
```

Additionally, this thead is not duplicate of any other thread in ask ubuntu!

Sorry, I am new here and dont know with this forum yet!

I emptyed trash already!
Then get some more access to my root... thank you!

But I see GParted LiveCD is for x86 machines.
Forgot to say I use 64bit machine and OS.
Is this OK for me?

Sure, I get useful and nice answers here and I will vote as soon I register.
Someone put me here automatically from "stack-overflow" and I am forbidden to give votes unregistered. Sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/19413/18612

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To gain access to the root-reserved space, change the size from 5% to 0,5%. As you are not on a server, it won't hurt anybody.

   ```
   sudo tune2fs -m 0.5 /dev/sda7
   ```
2. Resize with an ubuntu liveCD/liveUSB or with [Gparted LiveCD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php). It can move, shrink, grow partitions. But keep in mind, that you must one task at a time (eg. first shrink, then move ...).

Comment: I am unable to download "http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/". Is here other link where appropriate version can be downloaded from?

Comment: Try this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/latest/download?source=files

Comment: Thank you gajdipajti. I successfully grow critical partition on my disk with your kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You can empty the Trash. Open Nautilus, go to Trash and choose "Empty Trash".

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping desgua. Im my case is no need to clean trash but somebody will surelly need this advice.

Comment: - - Welcome ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have 113036984 1K blocks in /dev/sda7 and this makes around 100 G if I'm not too rusty in math. You are out of disk space, however that's not because your root file system is too small. 100 G should be sufficient for a standart installation where you do not store much stuff.

You can do some partition magic with gparted to enlarge /dev/sda7 (not /dev/sda1 !!!) However I believe you can just clean up some space. Most probably you do not want to store 100 G data, since it seems you are not aware of it.

Comment: Yes, you right! I have to grow partition /dev/sda7/. Thank you.