# Starting program from USB disk

Tags: 11.10

I have to fix issues on my filesystem for which I ask for help in this thread:
[Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Low Disk Space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92893/ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-low-disk-space)

In order to do this I have to install one "tuxboot-linux-25-64bit" which I download and copy do clean formated (fat32) USB Disk. This file have to download linux ISO file with gparted live cd.

But when I doubleclick this file it not runs program but opens "geany"??
Allow executing file as program is checked under properties (from nautilus).

I would like to make systemdisk with gparted installed so please help.

Ubuntu Gnome 11.10 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flash drive is likely mounted noexec.

Copy the file to your home directory , make it executable if needed, and run it as root.

```
chmod a+x ~/your_file
sudo ./your_file
```

Comment: In order this system to install propperly it is needed to run this file from target drive. Can I reformat drive or anything else?

Comment: Try unmounting it from nautilus, but do not eject or remove the device. Then mount it as root. `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt -o exec,rw` Then run it from /mnt

Comment: Thank you bodhi.zazen. I successfuly created my boot USB with gparted!

Comment: you are most welcome and more important glad you got it working.