# Installed Ubuntu on 12.04 on my MacBook Air now I want to expand the partition

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning, mac

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a 40GB partition on my Mac Book Air (5,2). I'm having so much fun with it, I'm ready to make the switch permanently and replace it as the primary OS on my machine.

I realize I can wipe the machine and start from scratch, but I'm looking for alternatives since I like my current setup. Options are...

1. Create a backup and restore the back up to a larger partition (Assuming I should keep the default OS X install for firmware updates)
2. Create a backup and restore to the entire drive (create a restore usb stick for OSX - not sure if that's possible?)
3. re-size my current partition and wipe the OS X partition and either, A. re-install OS X (similar to option 1) or B. create the USB key (similar to option 2).

Thoughts? Any other suggestions?

Would also like thoughts on the "optimal" or "best practice" for partitioning Ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest the third one. Resize your current partition , and make such adjustment that you don't need to wipe out os x partition. This will be less time consuming rather taking backup and restore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) which comes with the LiveCD. You can use it to shrink, expand the size of the hard-disk or delete/add new hard-disks.

but first back up your files.
then use an Ubuntu Live CD.
and boot from the liveCD.
and then open `Gparted`.
then do your operations from the Live environment.

I myself have done resizing many times and have never ever come across any data loss.
Well, if you are a pessimist or tend to get a bit panicky at times, i would suggest a back-up of the most important data.

[image]

here is a great tutorial on how to use Gparted. If you need any help check it out.

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html

May be helpful: 
[How can I expand a partition into non adjacent free space using GParted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19413/how-can-i-expand-a-partition-into-non-adjacent-free-space-using-gparted)