# GParted merging unallocated space to Ubuntu partition not working?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I had deleted my hackintosh OS from `/dev/sda1` so I could expand my Ubuntu partition. Also this is just one physical hard drive. I think it would be the filesystem `sda5` that would need to be expanded. However I am still pretty new to Linux in general, so it could be the `sda4` extended partition instead. While playing with GParted I did notice that if allocated space was within the drop down area of the partitions, it can see that space and re-add it.

I watched some videos, but they didn't quite help me in figuring the problem out. They all had "gray space" after the data and free space on the existing partition.

[image]

I don't know what to do. Also my Terminal knowledge is limited. I also have no issues having to re-install Ubuntu if needed, but I can't do anything to the Windows 7 partition on sda3 as it has important files. Please advise.

Comment: There isn't much to do. The unallocated space is nowhere near /dev/sda4, and there are several other partitions in between. To merge them, you'd need to do a major overhaul.

Comment: boot from your usb or cd 'live' and run gparted there. you can allocate that free space as you like. just don't make the / "root" partition smaller than it is because there is danger to lose important files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfornately you cannot do this easily, because there are several partions in between the ext4 and unallocated area. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19413/how-can-i-expand-a-partition-into-non-adjacent-free-space-using-gparted?rq=1)  is similar to your issue. And has the answer to your initial intent.

However, you can set that unallocated space as your `home`, and your current ext4 drive as `root`. That way you can utilize your current drive structure.

You can google several tutorials for custom ubuntu hdd partition. One such is [this](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/gparted-partition-guide-for-linux-and-windows-users/797).

Comment: Please add the important contents of that link in case it changes.

Comment: @George Did you mean the last link ? It's a full blown article with almost 500+ line, I'm not sure how to summarize it. If you suggest, I can remove the link though.

Comment: I think the Ubuntu-mate one, but i can't see it here.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to work around my issue. I formatted the unallocated space to an `ext4` file system format and it became `/dev/sda1` via live usb. I then re-installed Ubuntu to the latest distro. During the partition process during the re-install, I had `sda1` be `\home` and sda5 be `\`. It looks like it is working well now. Thank you to everyone who commented and posted an answer!

Comment: Glad to know you were successful. Welcome to linux world :D